# Understanding Approximate Dynamic Programming

Tags: optimization, markov-process, reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming

I am trying to write a paper for my optimization class about Approximate Dynamic Programming. I found a few good papers but they all seem to dive straight into the material without talking about the basics so I am really lost about what it is.

In class we talked a little bit about "Dynamic Programming" but I can't seem to find out the difference between regular DP and ADP. What are we approximating? One source says

> Many problems in these fields are described by continuous variables, whereas DP and RL can find exact solutions only in the discrete case. Therefore, 
>   approximation is essential in practical DP and RL.

so I thought ADP is used for continuous time but then another paper states

> Approximate Dynamic Programming (ADP) is a powerful technique to solve large scale discrete time multistage stochastic control processes

So is it for discrete time or continuous? Or both?

Similarly, a lot of sources on ADP talk about reinforcement learning but they don't distinguish the two. Are they both both pretty much the same things or is there a distinct difference?